# Flask SQLite error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am building a link shortening service using Flask and SQLite.
The shortening part is done , but I am having issues calling the actual URL from the SQLite db.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE WEB_URL(
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        URL TEXT ,
        S_URL TEXT ,
        COUNTER INT DEFAULT 0
        );
```

And the get redirect function is :

```
@app.route('/<short_url>')
def redirect(short_url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('url.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    select_row = '''
        SELECT URL FROM WEB_URL WHERE S_URL = %s
        '''%(short_url)
    result_cur = cursor.execute(select_row)
    try:
        redirect_url = result_cur.fetchnone()[0]
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return redirect(redirect_url)   
    except Exception as e:
        error  = e 
        return render_template('index.html' , error = error)
```

It's throwing an operational error:

```
   result_cur = cursor.execute(select_row)
OperationalError: no such column: favicon.ico
```

Now I have never ever mentioned favicon.ico in my code.
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks!

Comment: `favicon.ico` is probably queried by the browser to your root address for displaying a small icon of your web link in the browser tab. To prevent this you need to sanitize the `short_url`. You must not assume that the client would always enter valid web address, It may inject some SQL program using this link as well. So make sure `short_url` is properly sanitized before querying data base

Comment: You have a huge SQL injection issue here; you should only ever use query parameters! `cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM WEB_URL WHERE S_URL = ?", (short_url,))`. You do *not* need to commit the transaction either, you are not making any changes to your database (at least, not intentionally, but with that wide open SQL injection issue you never know).

Comment: Your error message rendering actually tells an attacker how to adjust their injection attempts; I'd not expose that much information about your error to the requestor.

Comment: I'll try the fix and let u guys know. , Thanks!